# Best Practice for TwentyTwentyOne Child Theme?

Tags: wordpress-theming

I'm currently adjusting a child theme of TwentyTwentyOne with some minor changes. Originally my plan was to copy template files, after some lookup in the code I realiced there might be a more clever way.

Apprently they have made a lot of functions for parts (eg. twenty_twenty_one_entry_meta_footer() for a lot of parts and actually check if they dont exist before (https://github.com/WordPress/twentytwentyone/blob/ba9f20cad89163761185c0467b346ba42541ae22/inc/template-tags.php#L57)

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'twenty_twenty_one_entry_meta_footer' ) ) {
    function twenty_twenty_one_entry_meta_footer() {
```

As I have actually only smaller minor changes I wonder if setting those functions might be "best practice" in that context? Where would I actually set those? in the functions.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pluggable Functions was the thin I was searching for: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions

And goes to functions.php